# Why in “:normal”command ^[ seems doesn't work with A? (vim)

Tags: vim

Today, I learnt a bit of vim normal command, and below is my experiment:

```
:normal i Insert ^[ yyp
:normal A Append ^[ yyp


# RESULT OF EXECUTE FIRST COMMAND FOR SEVERAL TIMES
 Insert Insert  
  Insert Insert Insert  
   Insert Insert Insert Insert  
    Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert  
    Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert  


 # RESULT OF EXECUTE SECOND COMMAND FOR SEVERAL TIMES
 Append  Append  Append  Append  Append  Append
```

Why the second command ignored the yyp part? How to fix it?

Comment: in cmd No.2 have you typed `C-V ESC` for the `^[`? btw, the space after `^[` should be removed, particularly if you used `:norm` instead of `:norm!`

Comment: @Kent, of course `C-V ESC` is entered. Why the space could be the trouble maker? And why cmd No.1 works with space after [Esc]?

Comment: I didn't say the space in cmd1 or cmd2  caused problem. you used `:norm`, all mappings will work too. read help doc about `:norm! and :norm` The space is not necessary, and could have problem if you have mapping on that.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove space between ^[ and yyp